# What to eat before and after gain weight workout?

Tags: exercise, weight-gain

I want to gain weight, but im confused what to eat before and after exercise(gain weight).Can someone name healthy foods or snacks? And also do i need to eat more on before or after exercise?
Also want to know if its advisable to exercise early in the morning?

Comment: You need to be more specific so that the answers we produce are more in line with what you are asking. "gain weight" , for what purpose to gain weight? Gain muscle, build lean muscle tissue is more specific.

Comment: @ghost_zfh, im a women, i dont want super muscle,just want to get big like volleyball players,they look like healthy but no huge muscle, I hope you get my point.And you know i dont know what lean muscle looks like,sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your strategy depends on whether you're looking to put on muscle, or just general weight. If you're looking to simply become heavier, its pretty simple; you just need to eat more calories than you're burning. Since you're exercising with it, however, it looks like you're looking to gain muscle mass.

The most important part to gaining muscle mass will be eating an adequate amount of protein throughout the day. You should shoot for something like [1.8g/kg](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22150425), as this ratio will allow your body to make the most of your workouts in terms of muscle gains. You'll want to eat enough carbs to give you the energy to effectively do your workouts; if you're doing cardio work that amount will be higher. [60-70%](http://healthyeating.sfgate.com/recommended-amount-percent-carbohydrates-per-day-7287.html) of your daily calories (every carb is 4 calories) should come from carbohydrates if you're looking to gain weight. Cutting out deserts and fast foods will help to ensure that a significant portion of the weight you put on will be muscle, as these strategies will help keep your total Calorie intake from ballooning too high.

There's a number of different types of food which will work well for your goals; I'll list some here, but really anything that fits into the mold of high protein and lower fat/calories will suit your goals.

1. Cold cut meats (Turkey, ham, chicken) - These types of meats all will provide you with a lot of protein, while very low in fat and calories. Throwing them into a sandwich can be a great way to include some carbs as well; just make sure not to go too heavy on the mayo.
2. Eggs - A couple eggs a day provides many nutrients and protein, if you're looking to eat more than that, you may want to consider egg whites to avoid consuming too much cholesterol.
3. Red meats - While these have more fat than the cold cut meats, in your effort to gain weight you don't need to be as concerned with fat.
4. Fish - Another great source of protein and very low in fat.
5. Greek yogurt, skim milk - These types of dairy products provide protein without the fat of regular yogurt or whole milk.
6. Beans - Certain types of beans (soy, kidney, white, lima) have lots of protein.
7. Nuts - While generally higher in fat, these still provide great protein benefits.

In addition to these sorts of foods for protein, incorporate grains into your meals for the carbs, and you can include fruits and vegetables for their nutritional benefits.

Regarding when to eat these foods, it really depends on what works for you. If your stomach is comfortable with you eating before a workout, that works fine; generally, however, it works best to keep the meal before a workout light, and then consume more protein after. If you're working out at 5pm, this might mean eating a larger lunch and then nothing until after your workout; if you're working out at 2pm, you could eat a light lunch then an early dinner after. The important thing will be to be working out and consuming the right amounts of protein and carbs; the timing is of significantly less importance.

Working out in the morning can be a great way to kick off the day, but in terms of whether its best for you, it again depends on what you're comfortable with. If you have enough energy in the morning to hit your numbers and work out with intensity, then go for it; if you're dragging yourself to the gym and performing a sluggish workout, it might be best to wait until the afternoon. The effective workout is what's important, not the timing of it. In addition, sleep is also important, so if workout out early will impact your sleep, it'd be best to wait until later.

Comment: im a women, i dont want super muscle like other women whos into gym,just want to get big like volleyball players,they look like healthy but no huge muscle, I hope you get or imagine what kind of body i want to achieve,get big, but i dont want to look a hercules women.

Comment: @meanderingmoose based on normal office work 9-6 which time is more good for excerise mor or eve.In evening its starving for food and morning its like difficult to wake up

Comment: @Niang It'd take years to even get close to beginning to look like a "hercules woman", that's not something you have to worry about as you begin to exercise

Comment: @user285oo6 really depends on what you feel best with, you could try adding a little caffeine to your morning to give you energy for an AM workout, or changing your eating pattern throughout the day to keep you full for a PM workout